# Using system date to filter on

Tags: sql, greenplum

Running a sql query to grab data with dates in a given range. stdt is a date data type. This is the problematic code:

```
    select hofc_wrk_unit_uid
    from mhal_rep.stusha
    where STDT BETWEEN date('2010-01-21') AND to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    and ibmsnap_operation not in ('D')
    and stus_cd in ('CLSD')
```

I keep getting the error " The column 'SYSDATE' does not exist"

How do I make it call the SYSDATE function and stop looking for a column called sysdate?

Tried this:

```
    select hofc_wrk_unit_uid
    from mhal_rep.stushh
    where STDT BETWEEN date('2010-01-21') AND SYSDATE()
    and stus_endt BETWEEN date('2010-01-21') AND SYSDATE()
    and stus_cd in ('DWPC')
    and ibmsnap_operation not in ('D')
```

and am getting function sysdate() does not exist

Comment: What's the database? PostgreSQL, MariaDB, SQLite, HSQL, etc.

Comment: using one extremum points is of type `date` and the other of type `char` for a `date range` has no sense.

Comment: Why are you doing the to_char() anyway?

Comment: Thinking the same thing. You should compare using dates, not chars.

Comment: PostgreSQL; it's a greenplum edw

Comment: Cannot do anything since sysdate not even recognized

Comment: use `current_date`

Comment: Use `current_date` or `now()`

Comment: `sysdate` is a pseudo column used in oracle, not in postgres

Comment: And remove `to_char()`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select hofc_wrk_unit_uid
    from mhal_rep.stushh
    where STDT BETWEEN date('2010-01-21') AND current_date
    and stus_endt BETWEEN date('2010-01-21') AND current_date
    and stus_cd in ('DWPC')
    and ibmsnap_operation not in ('D')
```